# What does self.eval().function(x, y) do in the context of a class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I'm working with some old Python 2.6.5 code written by someone else and can't find a good explanation in the documentation for the `self.eval().func(2, 3)` syntax below. I understand `eval` will execute strings of code, i.e. `eval('1 + 3')` will output `4`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def func(self, x, y):
        print '%s %s' % (x,y)

    def func2(self):
        return self.eval().func(2, 3)

x = Foo()
x.func2()
```

Results in the error:

```
'Foo' object has no attribute 'eval'.
```

In the context of a Python 2.6 class object what does `self.eval().somefunction` do? Is it similar to a static class in other languages? Seems the intent is to call the `func` method, but why not just call it directly? What is the added value of the `eval()`?

Comment: `self.eval()` would be calling an instance, class or static method named `eval`. That's it. It's possibly related to the built-in `eval` function, but there's no way to tell from what you've posted. If you get an `AttributeError`, then your guess is as good as anyone else's as to why that was ever there. Also `eval` evaluates, it doesn't execute (that's what `exec` does!)

Comment: Also I just installed 2.6.6 via `pyenv` (they didn't have 2.6.5) and got the same error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for your insights! As I mentioned I am updating someone else legacy code. The line I mention is working in my 2.6.5 environment and what it does is call "somefunction" and pass a couple of parameters. There is no "eval" attribute in the class. i.e. I've set a break point and tried type(self.eval()) and get an error. I'm running inside a proprietary framework within a large corporate enterprise so I'm thinking it must be some magic under the covers of the framework and not entirely standard python. Thanks again!